# How to get the stats of total mobile data used in give time period(eg, last month) by all the application in android

Tags: android, usage-statistics, android-data-usage

I'm trying to get the mobile data used by all application in previous month( or week) or between a given time period. I want to get the mobile data usage history. I see that android is doing this by default now. Is it possible to get this information by code?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get this information by code?

Not in any documented or supported fashion, at least through Android 4.4. You are welcome to collect this data yourself by periodically [examining `TrafficStats`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html), though.