# How to get mobile data usage of current month without monitoring it periodically using API 22 or less?

Tags: android, android-data-usage, mobile-data, networkstatsmanager, android-trafficstats

I need to know how much mobile data the device has used since the start of the current month, I know how to do it monitoring the device, but there are two problems with this:

1 - The device I'm working with has very low performance, the network is poor as well, and there are other constant running services in it and a lot of stuff my application needs to do when starting, so it is in it's limit already.

2 - I need to get usage info that exists previously than my application (it's not a public application, it's a business one and we have our own devices and apps).

I know that I can see this data going in the settings of the device and choosing "data usage", but I need to do this programmatically, and it is exactly this I need, like if my app was going to the settings and getting the data usage info.

I've already searched about [TrafficStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) and [NetworkStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html). I've also searched all around [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) and saw a lot of similar questions, they aren't as much specific as mine though and they are either unresolved, use monitoring in the app itself or uses API 23+.
Some of the questions I already searched:

[How to check mobile data usage programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025444/how-to-check-mobile-data-usage-programmatically) - this just gives me the data since the device boot.

[How to get Data usage on android by both wifi and Mobile data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064647/how-to-get-data-usage-on-android-by-both-wifi-and-mobile-data) - Tells how to split the info by application.

[How to get Data usage for last 1 month in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908483/how-to-get-data-usage-for-last-1-month-in-android) - It's about last month, not the current month, and it's not currently answered. (Help this fella too if you can, other people also get to his questions when searching about this).

[How can I find the data usage on a per-application basis on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-a-per-application-basis-on-android) - it's about monitoring, I can't do it.

[How to get the stats of total mobile data used in give time period(eg, last month) by all the application in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230390/how-to-get-the-stats-of-total-mobile-data-used-in-give-time-periodeg-last-mont) - Here [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)'s answer tell that it is not possible, but this answer is from five years ago, so I'm hoping things has changed.

[How to get the GPRS Mobile data usage for 1 month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039874/how-to-get-the-gprs-mobile-data-usage-for-1-month) - Although it seems to be a good solution, I'm working with API level 19, and the max I can work with is API 22, that is the API of the devices.

The closer I could get was this [answer from rajeesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41695824/5791681), but the class he uses - [NetworkStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStats) - was implemented on API 23, so I can't use it.

I've also found something about reading the system files to get the info in [Alexandra Golovatyuk's blog](http://agolovatyuk.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-traffic-statistics-inside.html), but it does have some problems, like it does not show how to get the time info, so although I would have the data usage I wouldn't know what period it is from. And although I can root the majority of my devices and install system apps, I would prefer to avoid it and I have some other device models that I can't root. But if there's no other way, this way would also be helpful.